# How to implement a paper-styled "<select multiple>" box with Polymer, without "paper-dropdown-menu"?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, material-design

I'm working on a Polymer application that uses `iron-form` to submit a form to a back-end web-service. One of the elements in the form is a box where the user can select multiple elements.

Using the `paper-dropdown-menu` with a `paper-listbox` with `multi` set works, but the UX is horrible because the user can't see which elements are selected without opening the dropdown (and blocking other elements). Also - it requires more clicks to operate.

Ideally we'd just use the `paper-listbox` without the `paper-dropdown-menu`, as that is exactly the UI that we need - similar to HTML's classic `<select multiple>` but with a Material Design sheen. But without the `paper-dropdown-menu` wrapper, `iron-form` doesn't pick up on the `paper-listbox` selected values and will not submit those.

I've noticed that `iron-form` support classic HTML `<select>` (and even support the `multiple` behavior), but the UI for that is jarring in contrast with the rest of the form.

Is there something else that we can wrap around the `paper-listbox` to get the form to behave without modifying the original `paper-listbox` UI, or get `paper-dropdown-menu` to have an "always open" mode? If neither of those work (and I couldn't get either to work, BTW), what else can we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the `<paper-listbox>` in a custom element that implements [`<iron-form-element-behavior>`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form-element-behavior/Polymer.IronFormElementBehavior). The behavior exposes a [`value`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-form-element-behavior/Polymer.IronFormElementBehavior#property-value) property, which could be bound to [`<paper-listbox>.selectedValues`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-listbox/paper-listbox#property-selectedValues), allowing `<iron-form>` to submit the multiple listbox values:

```
<dom-module id="multi-listbox">
  <template>
    <paper-listbox multi selected-values="{{value}}">
      <content></content>
    </paper-listbox>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'multi-listbox',
      behaviors: [Polymer.IronFormElementBehavior]
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    _onResponse: function(e) {
      this._response = JSON.stringify(e.detail.response, null, 2);
    },
    _submit: function() {
      this._response = null;
      this.$.form.submit();
    }
  });
  
  Polymer({
    is: 'multi-listbox',

    behaviors: [
      Polymer.IronFormElementBehavior
    ],

    properties: {
      value: {
        type: Array,
        value: () => [],
        notify: true
      },
      invalid: {
        type: Boolean,
        reflectToAttribute: true
      }
    },

    validate: function() {
      const isValid = !this.required || !!(this.value && this.value.length > 0);
      this.invalid = !isValid;
      console.log('invalid', this.invalid);
      return isValid;
    },
    
    _clearError: function() {
      this.invalid = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-form/iron-form.html">
    <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-form-element-behavior/iron-form-element-behavior.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-validatable-behavior/iron-validatable-behavior.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        multi-listbox,
        paper-checkbox,
        paper-button {
          margin: 0.5em;
        }
      </style>
      <paper-checkbox active="{{_required}}">Required</paper-checkbox>
      <form is="iron-form"
            id="form"
            action="//httpbin.org/get"
            on-iron-form-response="_onResponse">
        <multi-listbox name="listbox-values" required="[[_required]]">
          <paper-item>Item 1</paper-item>
          <paper-item>Item 2</paper-item>
          <paper-item>Item 3</paper-item>
          <paper-item>Item 4</paper-item>
        </multi-listbox>
        <paper-button raised
                      on-tap="_submit">Submit</paper-button>
      </form>

      <pre>[[_response]]</pre>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
  
  <dom-module id="multi-listbox">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
        }

        paper-listbox {
          border: solid 2px lightgray;
        }

        :host([invalid]) paper-listbox {
          border: solid 2px var(--error-color, red);
        }
      </style>
      <paper-listbox multi
                     selected-values="{{value}}"
                     on-iron-activate="_clearError">
        <content></content>
      </paper-listbox>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/KNjYYB?editors=1010)